# Images broken after uploading Rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

Shows fine locally. But when I upload to Heroku, I get the following:

[image]

```
<%= image_tag('logo-red.png') %>
```

and it's located in assets/images/

I'm not using Turbolinks. Do I need to run a command on Heroku to solve this or is there some config setting I'm missing?

**edit 1: tried running `heroku run rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`**

**edit 2: response from heroku staff:**

*It looks like your app is properly compiling that image:
~/public/assets $ pwd
/app/public/assets
~/public/assets $ ls | grep logo-red
logo-red-a07050d882e1dba431cef2130d39f929c611eaf8b0ec3c50db0742ddccb14d93.png*

**edit 3: See attached screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Comment: Hmmm.. Still can't pinpoint the issue. I'm using gem 'rails_12factor' already and serving my asset via an image_tag.

Comment: by assets/images you mean app/assets/images?

Comment: yeah, app/assets/images

Comment: do you see the file with some hash within the `public/assets/` folder if you run `rake assets:precompile` on your local machine?

Comment: Can you provide the image path that is getting generated for the image, by inspecting the element. This might give us a hint....

Comment: Hey @Anti-Fun - see OP for edits :)

Answer (score 7):

Try running on your local computer:

```
rake assets:precompile
rake assets:clean
```

Then commit and push to heroku.

Also check your `production.rb` file and make sure everything related to compiling or precompiling is true and not false ie:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

Also, make sure rails_12factor is in your gemfile like so:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem on Heroku before - we solved it by `precompiling` the assets on Heroku itself:

```
$ heroku run rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

I know this is done when you push the repo to Heroku; it's one of those quirks which seems to be resolved if you compile the assets on their server.

You could also precompile locally as long as you make sure the `RAILS_ENV` is production:

`$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: hmmm.. gave this a shot but no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

After below answers if your problem still continuing

you ca try:

```
<%= asset_path 'logo-red.png' %>
```